# how to make typescript mixin a partial class

Tags: typescript

I want `class A` to inherit properties from `class B`, but I dont want to use `extends`. So I'm using a mixin. like so:

```
class A{
 someProp: String
 someMethod(){}
}

class B implements classA{
  someProp: String
  someMethod: () => void;
}
```

But I don't want to have to redefine all the properties and methods in `classA`,
so I'm trying to use `Partial` keyword like so:

```
class B implements Partial<classA>{}
```

I get a typescript compiler error: 
`A class may only implement another class or interface`

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: When you use `implements` you have to redefine all properties, it's not like `extends` which automatically get you all of the properties and you can then just override.

Comment: @NitzanTomer but you can use `class A {props;}` `interface B extends A{}` `class B {}` which will provide all the typing you need. Then you can use something like `assign` to handle the actual copying.

Comment: @AluanHaddad copying the members/methods won't be easy, `Object.assign` will deal with instance properties, but what about methods on the prototype? Also, what happens if class `B` redefines a certain member/method? it will be overridden once you do this copying.

Comment: @NitzanTomer right, there is no silver bullet, I was just pointing out that the type system can handle it via declaration merging. I would avoid the pattern entirely in favor of either class or object level mixins, both of which have solid support these days.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extends` with the mixin pattern.  This involves writing `A` as a mixin.

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function A<C extends Constructor>(Base: C) {
  return class extends Base {
    someProp: String
    someMethod(){}
  }

class B extends A(class {}) {}
```

Or if you are reeeally averse to that, use declaration merging to copy the public interface of A onto B.

```
class B {}
interface B extends A {}
Object.assign(B.prototype, A.prototype); // copy methods at runtime
```

The mixin approach is better and I would use it unless you have a justifiable reason to avoid it.